# Apache Ant 1.9.1 build.xml works fine with windows but throwing error with Linux

Tags: apache, ant, build.xml

I am trying to run my build.xml file. In windows its running fine but when i try to run the same build.xml in linux it throws below error

```
/ATG/TwoDegreeReplatformApp/twodegree/build/build.xml:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/ATG/apache-ant-1.9.4/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml:37: Problem: failed to create task or type componentdef
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Even i have checked the path variable in linux machine. Last week same script was working in Linux env but now started throwing error.

Below is my build file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Siebel" default="all-with-ws" basedir=".">

  <!-- Import global defaults and settings and common tasks -->
  <import file="${basedir}/buildtools/common.xml"/>

  <!-- To keep track of alters made to the schemas, place them in the sql.install.dir
       and name them with alter_core_xxx.sql and alter_catalog_xxx.sql. The following
       path declaration will pick them up, and they will be executed on the appropriate
       schema. -->
  <path id="alter.core.schema.files">
    <fileset dir="${sql.alter.dir}">
      <include name="alter_core*"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <path id="alter.catalog.schema.files">
    <fileset dir="${sql.alter.dir}">
      <include name="alter_catalog*"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <!-- ======================================= -->
  <!-- Task Definitions                        -->
  <!-- ======================================= -->
    <!-- Web Serice import task - generates Java classes based on WSDL files.
         This is a JAX (Java API for XML) resource.
     -->
  <taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport">
    <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    <classpath path="${dyn.classpath}" />
  </taskdef>

  <!-- ======================================= -->

  <!-- Define the all task.  We do this here because we need to call tasks
       imported in both the common.xml and deploy.xml files.  This may seem a
       bit odd but it feels better to segregate common tasks from j2ee
       deployment tasks and add this extra bit of layering than have one
       massive common task file which has tons of targets, making it difficult
       to read.  You get my point separating the tasks in multiple imports
       makes this complex environment easier to get around.  -->
  <target name="all"
          depends="clean,build,install"
          description="Cleans, builds, and installs the project.">
  </target>

  <!-- Does what 'all' does.
       Also builds and install the web services for the "import from Siebel"
       functionality.
    -->
  <target name="all-with-ws"
          depends="clean,build,install,make-install-ws"
          description="Cleans, builds, and installs the project.">
  </target>

  <!--
    Compiles and jars the code.
    Also copies the WSDL files into the classes dir to the JAR'd.
  -->
  <target name="build"
          depends="set-dynamo-classpath,wsdl2java,compile,copy-wsdl,-jar,-copylibs,build-versioned,build-publishingagent"
          description="Compiles and jars the code.">
  </target>

  <!-- Performs all requisite tasks for installing the module.
   -->
  <target name="install"
          depends="-init, -createdirs, -installcore, -install-web-app,install-versioned,install-publishingagent"
          description="Installs the codebase to the install directory.">
  </target>

  <!--
    Creates and installs the Siebel web services.
   -->
  <target name="make-install-ws"
    depends="create-ws,install-ws"
    description="" >
  </target>

  <!--
    Creates the Siebel web service.
  -->
  <target name="create-ws">
    <antcall target="copy-siebel-ws-script" />
    <exec executable="/bin/sh" dir="${dynamo.home}" failonerror="yes"
      os="Linux:SunOS:Mac OS X">
      <arg line="bin/generateSiebelWebService" />
    </exec>
    <exec executable="cmd" dir="${dynamo.home}" failonerror="yes"
      osfamily="windows">
      <arg line="/c bin\generateSiebelWebService.bat" />
    </exec>

    <move todir="${basedir}/SiebelWS/j2ee-apps" failonerror="yes">
      <fileset dir="${dynamo.home}" includes="SiebelWS.ear" />
    </move>
  </target>

  <!--
    Copies the web service generation scripts to $DYNAMO_HOME/bin
    so they have access to other ATG scripts.
  -->
  <target name="copy-siebel-ws-script">
    <copy todir="${dynamo.home}/bin" failonerror="yes">
      <fileset dir="${basedir}/wsGenScripts/" includes="generate*" />
    </copy>
  </target>

  <!--
    Installs the web services by copying them to the module directory.
  -->
  <target name="install-ws" >
    <!-- Copy the web service directory -->
    <copy todir="${install.dir}/SiebelWS">
      <fileset dir="${basedir}/SiebelWS/"/>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <!--
    Copy WSDL files into classes dir
   -->
  <target name="copy-wsdl">
    <copy todir="${classes.dir}/META-INF/wsdl">
      <fileset dir="${src.dir}/META-INF/wsdl"/>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <!--
    Creates Java source from the WSDL files provided.
    Calls another task to pass in the right classpath.
  -->
  <target name="wsdl2java">
    <antcall target="_wsdl2java" />
  </target>

  <!--
    Creates Java source from the WSDL files provided.
    This must be called from an antcall in order to get the right classpath.
  -->
  <target name="_wsdl2java" depends="set-dynamo-classpath">
      <echo>${gen-src.dir}</echo>
      <echo>${classes.dir}</echo>
    <mkdir dir="${gen-src.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <property name="quiet" value="true"/> 
    <wsimport keep="true"   quiet="${quiet}"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" 
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/SelfServiceAccount.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/SelfServiceAccount.wsdl"/>
    <wsimport  keep="true"  quiet="${quiet}"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/SelfServiceAddress.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/SelfServiceAddress.wsdl"/>
    <wsimport  keep="true"  quiet="${quiet}"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/SelfServiceContact.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/SelfServiceContact.wsdl"/>
    <wsimport  keep="true"  quiet="${quiet}"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/SelfServiceUser.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/SelfServiceUser.wsdl"/>
    <wsimport  keep="true" quiet="${quiet}"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/ProductConfigurator.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/ProductConfigurator.wsdl"/>
    <wsimport  keep="true" quiet="${quiet}"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/PromotionWebService.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/PromotionWebService.wsdl"/>
    <wsimport  keep="true" quiet="${quiet}"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/CalculatePriceWS.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/CalculatePriceWS.wsdl"/>
    <wsimport  keep="true" quiet="${quiet}"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/SelfServiceAccountBillingProfile.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/SelfServiceAccountBillingProfile.wsdl"/>
    <wsimport  keep="true" quiet="${quiet}"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/QuotingWebService.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/QuotingWebService.wsdl"/>
    <wsimport  keep="true" quiet="${quiet}"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/OrderDetailWebService.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/OrderDetailWebService.wsdl"/>     
    <wsimport  keep="true" quiet="${quiet}"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/OrderWebService.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/OrderWebService.wsdl"/>   
    <wsimport  keep="true"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/AssetManagement.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/AssetManagement.wsdl"/>
    <wsimport  keep="true"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/AssetManagementComplex.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/AssetManagementComplex.wsdl"/>
    <wsimport keep="true" quiet="${quiet}"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/QuoteEligibilityCompatibility.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/QuoteEligibilityCompatibility.wsdl"/>
    <wsimport  keep="true"
      sourcedestdir="${gen-src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
      wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/CatalogWebService.wsdl"
      wsdllocation="http://localhost/wsdl/CatalogWebService.wsdl"/>   
  </target>

    <!-- Installs the JSP files to the target WAR directory.
   -->
  <target name="install-jsps" description="Copy JSPs">
    <filter token="*.js*" value="${install.dir}/j2ee-apps/Siebel/siebel.war" />
    <copy todir="${install.dir}/j2ee-apps/Siebel/siebel.war" preservelastmodified="true" filtering="true" encoding="ISO-8859-1">
     <fileset dir="${basedir}/j2ee/siebel.war" />
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target name="-install-web-app" description="Installs all module's web applications into installation directory.">
    <!-- Copy config files only and apply filtering to them. -->
    <copy todir="${install.j2ee.dir}/${module.name}">
      <fileset dir="${j2ee.dir}"/>
    </copy>
    <!-- Copy all necessary taglibs into each target WEB-INF directory. -->
    <foreach param="target.webinf.dir" target="-copy-taglibs">
      <path>
        <dirset dir="${install.j2ee.dir}/${module.name}">
          <include name="**/WEB-INF"/>
        </dirset>
      </path>
    </foreach>
  </target>

  <target name="build-versioned" 
          depends="set-dynamo-classpath"
          description="Builds the Java code in the Versioned sub-module">

    <mkdir dir="${classes.versioned.dir}" />

    <echo message="DYNAMO CLASSPATH = ${dyn.classpath}"/>
    <property name="prop.classpath" refid="classpath" />
    <echo message="CLASSPATH = ${prop.classpath}"/>

    <javac srcdir="${src.versioned.dir}"
           destdir="${classes.versioned.dir}"
           debug="true"
           deprecation="false"
           optimize="false"
           source="1.5"
           target="1.5"
           includeantruntime="false"
           verbose="${javac.verbose.bool}">

      <classpath refid="classpath"/>
      <classpath path="${dyn.classpath}"/>
      <classpath path="${classes.dir}"/>

      <include name="**/*.java" />
    </javac>

    <!-- create classes.jar -->
    <mkdir dir="${build.versioned.dir}/lib" />
    <jar jarfile="${build.versioned.dir}/lib/classes.jar"
         basedir="${classes.versioned.dir}/"
         includes="**"/>

    <!-- copy config files -->
    <mkdir dir="${build.tempconfig.versioned.dir}" />
    <copy todir="${build.tempconfig.versioned.dir}" filtering="true">
      <fileset dir="${config.versioned.dir}" />
    </copy>

  </target>

  <target name="install-versioned" description="Installs the Versioned sub-module">
    <!-- copy classes.jar -->
    <mkdir dir="${build.versioned.dir}/lib"/>
    <copy file="${build.versioned.dir}/lib/classes.jar" todir="${install.versioned.dir}/lib"/>
    <!-- copy config files -->
    <mkdir dir="${install.versioned.dir}/config" />
    <copy todir="${install.versioned.dir}/config">
      <fileset dir="${build.tempconfig.versioned.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <!-- Copy manifest file -->
    <mkdir dir="${install.versioned.dir}/META-INF" />
    <copy file="${versioned.dir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" todir="${install.versioned.dir}/META-INF"/>
  </target>


  <target name="build-publishingagent" 
          depends="set-dynamo-classpath"
          description="Builds the publishingagent sub-module">

    <mkdir dir="${classes.publishingagent.dir}" />

    <echo message="DYNAMO CLASSPATH = ${dyn.classpath}"/>
    <property name="prop.classpath" refid="classpath" />
    <echo message="CLASSPATH = ${prop.classpath}"/>

    <javac srcdir="${src.publishingagent.dir}"
           destdir="${classes.publishingagent.dir}"
           debug="true"
           deprecation="false"
           optimize="false"
           source="1.5"
           target="1.5"
           includeantruntime="false"
           verbose="${javac.verbose.bool}">

      <classpath refid="classpath"/>
      <classpath path="${dyn.classpath}"/>
      <classpath path="${classes.dir}"/>

      <include name="**/*.java" />
    </javac>

    <!-- create classes.jar -->
    <mkdir dir="${build.publishingagent.dir}/lib" />
    <jar jarfile="${build.publishingagent.dir}/lib/classes.jar"
         basedir="${classes.publishingagent.dir}/"
         includes="**"/>

    <!-- copy config files -->
    <mkdir dir="${build.tempconfig.publishingagent.dir}" />
    <copy todir="${build.tempconfig.publishingagent.dir}" filtering="true">
      <fileset dir="${config.publishingagent.dir}" />
    </copy>
  </target> 

  <target name="install-publishingagent" description="Installs the PublishingAgent sub-module">
    <!-- copy classes.jar -->
    <mkdir dir="${build.publishingagent.dir}/lib"/>
    <copy file="${build.publishingagent.dir}/lib/classes.jar" todir="${install.publishingagent.dir}/lib"/>
    <!-- copy config files -->
    <mkdir dir="${install.publishingagent.dir}/config" />
    <copy todir="${install.publishingagent.dir}/config">
      <fileset dir="${build.tempconfig.publishingagent.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <!-- Copy manifest file -->
    <mkdir dir="${install.publishingagent.dir}/META-INF" />
    <copy file="${publishingagent.dir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" todir="${install.publishingagent.dir}/META-INF"/>
  </target>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ANT error indicates that your build is missing jars required by a 3rd party ANT task.

The following documentation describes the wsimport task:

https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.3/docs/wsimportant.html

States the external task is declared as follows:

```
<taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport">
 <classpath
    path="jaxws.classpath"/>
</taskdef>
```

With the following description of the classpath:

> where jaxws.classpath is a reference to a path-like structure, defined
>   elsewhere in the build environment, and contains the list of classes
>   required by the JAX-WS tools.

So looks like you need to doublecheck the path declaration in your build and ensure that the JAX-WS jars are installed.

Answer (score 0):

There's missing information in your `build.xml` file:

```
<import file="${basedir}/buildtools/common.xml"/>
```

Much of your `build.xml` is embedded in that `common.xml` file. You listed your entire `build.xml`, but not that file.

For example, your `taskdef` depends upon `classpath` being set, and `${dyn.classpath}` being defined. They're not defined in your `build.xml` file. You also use `foreach` which I assume comes from the Ant Contrib jar, but the `<taskdef>` from your `build.xml` doesn't contain that either.

I suspect that your Windows Ant may contain third party jars in `$ANT_HOME/lib`, or that other setup issues may exist that you depend upon on your Windows machine, but aren't in that Linux machine.